# query all the rows with same string(but partial strings was given)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to show a query where colname - DueDateTime can be verified either date or time (its datatype is VARCHAR only & its content is date & time values separated with a white space)

Using a WHERE condition if any of the value is true, because I have many rows with same date but different time, I want to show all with the same dates.

```
`SELECT * FROM NAME_TBL WHERE DueDate = ?`
```

Comment: try something like : `where DueDate like %yourDate%`

Comment: It would be better if you use datetime type. By the way, the question is unclear. Could you make it specific?

Comment: Show sample output, in what way you want

Comment: You should avoid using `varchar` for fields that should contain dates/times - use the correct type and this question will resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

My information is specific but the question is misleading so I changed the question title.
M.Waqas Pervez has the right answer but it should be %'yourDate'%

Answer (score -1):

you can use groupby clause on DueDate.

Answer (score -1):

try below query.

```
SELECT * FROM NAME_TBL WHERE Convert(Date,DueDate) = '2016-11-25'
```